# Координатная сетка

Tags: c#, wpf

Этот код рисует координатную сетку на окне и перекрывает остальные компоненты

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfPhy
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Canvas canvasObj = new Canvas();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void InitChart()
        {
            int sX = 40;//шаг по оси x(px)
            int sY = 40;//шаг по оси y(px)
            int nXs = 5;//шаг по оси x
            int nYs = 5;//шаг по оси y
            int nX = nXs;
            int nY = nYs;
            this.Content = canvasObj;
            Line(35,main.Height-150, main.Width-25, main.Height-150, Colors.Black,1.5,false);
            Line(35, main.Height - 150, 35, 10, Colors.Black,1.5,false);
            for (int i = 30+sX; i <= main.Width - 10-sX; i += sX)
            {
                Line(i, main.Height - 147,i,main.Height - 153, Colors.Black,1.5,false);
                Line(i, main.Height - 156,i,10, Colors.Black,1,true);
                Text(i, main.Height-140, nX.ToString(), Colors.Black);
                nX += nXs;
            }
            for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(main.Height-150-sY); i >=10; i -= sY)
            {
                Line(32, i,38,i, Colors.Black,1.5,false);
                Line(41, i,main.Width-25,i, Colors.Black,1,true);
                Text(10, i, nY.ToString(), Colors.Black);
                nY += nYs;
            }

        }
        private void Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, Color color, double ST, bool dash)
        {

            Line lineObj = new Line();
            lineObj.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color);
            lineObj.StrokeThickness = ST;
            if (dash)
            {
                DoubleCollection dashes = new DoubleCollection();
                dashes.Add(5);
                dashes.Add(2);
                lineObj.StrokeDashArray = dashes;
            }
            lineObj.X1 = x1;
            lineObj.X2 = x2;
            lineObj.Y1 = y1;
            lineObj.Y2 = y2;
            canvasObj.Children.Add(lineObj);
        }
        private void Text(double x, double y, string text, Color color)
        {

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();

            textBlock.Text = text;

            textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color);

            Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, x);

            Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, y);

            canvasObj.Children.Add(textBlock);

        }

        private void main_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                canvasObj.Children.Clear();
                InitChart();
                MessageBox.Show("Max");
            }
            else
            {
                canvasObj.Children.Clear();
                InitChart();                
            }
        }

    }
}
```

как сделать чтобы координатная сетка рисовалась на отдельном компоненте canvas?

Comment: а что такое main

Comment: Ошибка 1 Имя "main" отсутствует в текущем контексте что делать ?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:
    this.Content = canvasObj;

Свойство контент может содержать только один объект -- обычно это контейнер (чаще всего Grid), вы же легкой рукой грохнули содержащийся на форме грид и вместо него установили канвас, он конечно тоже контейнер, но теперь все элементы формы надо располагать на нем заново.

Comment: как мне сделать чтобы эта сетка отрисовывалась в отдельном компоненте-контейнере?

Comment: Во-первых поместить Canvas не в Content, а на Grid

<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     определить строки
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     определить столбцы
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Canvas Name="canvasObj" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Canvas>
</Grid> 

Во-вторых в обязательном порядке почитать Петзольда :)